# If $\operatorname{Mod}(T_1 \cup T_2) = \emptyset$ then for some $\sigma$, $T_1 \vDash \sigma$ and $T_2 \vDash \neg \sigma$

Tags: proof-writing, first-order-logic, proof-explanation

Problem description: if $T_1$ and $T_2$ are theories such that $\operatorname{Mod}(T_1 \cup T_2) = \emptyset$, then there is a $\sigma$ such that $T_1 \vDash \sigma$ and $T_2 \vDash \neg \sigma$.

I don’t understand how to approach this. Is it even true if I’m not given that $T_1$ and $T_2$ are consistent?

Hints only please; no full solutions. Thanks!

Comment: If $T_1$ or $T_2$ is inconsistent then it's definitely true :) (Think about it.) So you don't have to worry about that as a special case.

Comment: Also, you mean $\vdash$, not $\vDash$. The latter holds between *models* and sentences.

Comment: Well, the problem specifically uses $\vDash$. It’s from Logic and Structure, van Dalen 2013 (p110).

Comment: But I can just use the completeness theorem to get around that anyway, if I’m not mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T_1 \cup T_2$ is inconsistent, then $T_1 \cup T_2 \vdash \bot$, where $\bot$ is some falsehood such as $\exists x\,(x\neq x)$. Let $S_i$ be all the sentences of $T_i$ that occur in the proof of $\bot$, $i = 1,2$. Then $S_1 \cup S_2\vdash \bot$.

Now let $\sigma_i = \bigwedge_{\varphi\in S_i} \varphi, i = 1,2$. Then 
$$
\vdash (\sigma_1 \land \sigma_2) \to \bot,
$$
i.e.
$$
\vdash \sigma_1 \to \neg\, \sigma_2.
$$
Note that $T_i \vdash \sigma_i, i = 1,2$.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! Do I need to do separate cases for $T_1$ or $T_2$ being inconsistent, or does this method work for those too?

Comment: This works if either one is inconsistent, as all you need is the fact $T_i\vdash \sigma_i$. Take $\sigma = \sigma_2$. If, say, $T_1$ is inconsistent, then it proves everything, in particular the negation of something that $T_2$ proves; but there's no need to treat that situation separately.

Comment: You're welcome. Little correction to my previous comment: take $\sigma = \neg \sigma_2$. Or take $\sigma = \sigma_1$ — both work.

Answer (score 2):

Theorem (Compactness). A theory $T$ is consistent iff every finite $S\subset T$ is consistent.Theorem (Henkin). A theory is consistent iff it has a model. So if $T_1\cup T_2$ has no model, then it is inconsistent.

Suppose $T_1$ and $T_2$ are consistent. By Compactness, we have $\neg$ Con $(T_1\cup U)$ for some finite $U\subset T_2,$ and since Con $(T_1)$ we have $U\neq \phi.$  Take $u \in U$ and let $W=U\backslash \{u\}.$ Let $\sigma$ be $[(\land_{w\in W})\implies \neg u].$

I will leave the cases $\neg$ Con$(T_1)$ and $\neg$ Con$(T_2)$ to someone else.

Comment: But the theories might have infinitely many sentences.

Comment: That's what happens when you watch the NHL playoffs at the same time.  I completely re-wrote it.